# Is it okay to clear the sys_domain table in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

We migrated a TYPO3 project to a new server and had the problem that preview links from the backend point to the old URL.

I found in `sys_domain` to entries

- example.com
- staging.example.com

Now for example I am on my dev system `example.com.dev.local.mycompany.de`. I found that when truncating `sys_domain` everything works fine at the first glance.

But is that a valid solution or would you expect additional problems? Is this table only needed on multi domain setups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to keep your sys_domain records up to date with the actual domains that point to your TYPO3. Even if you just serve one page for one domain. In that case you are done quite fast.

Advantages of keeping your sys_domain records up to date:

- It will be easier to add a 2nd website on a different domain to your TYPO3.
- You can use the "Always prepend links" feature with e.g. `config.absRefPrefix = /`
- Some extensions will use this records for configuration on a per domain basis

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need that data only when using multiple domains and to define, which pages are associated with which domain.